# C# Created ZIP file is invalid

Tags: c#

I'm trying to zip multi files to a zip file, but the generated zip file is invalid, my code is here, I don't what's going wrong here.

```
public static void DownloadRQFFiles(string[] sourceFileList, string saveFullPath)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    foreach (string filePath in sourceFileList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(filePath);
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            byte[] fileNameBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileName);
            byte[] sizeBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileNameBytes.Length);
            ms.Write(sizeBytes, 0, sizeBytes.Length);
            ms.Write(fileNameBytes, 0, fileNameBytes.Length);
            byte[] fileContentBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
            ms.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(fileContentBytes.Length), 0, 4);
            ms.Write(fileContentBytes, 0, fileContentBytes.Length);
        }
    }
    ms.Flush();
    ms.Position = 0;
    using (FileStream zipFileStream = File.Create(saveFullPath))
    {
        using (GZipStream zipStream = new GZipStream(zipFileStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
        {
            ms.Position = 0;
            ms.CopyTo(zipStream);
        }
    }
    ms.Close();
}
```

Comment: GZipStream generates .gz files. Maybe you meant to use [ZipFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-compress-and-extract-files) instead?

Comment: It was my understanding that GZipStream is not meant for handling multiple files, as it doesn't have any file headers or infrastructure information that is required.

Comment: @IanBoggs, yes GZipStream can only handle single file, so I write all things to one file "ms" first.

Comment: @sven.xia So how are you deflating the files afterwards ?

Comment: @IanBoggs I used GZip...but it seems that it generates .gz file. I'm not sure about this, I cannot use a third party namespace, so I tried GZip...

Comment: @sven.xia What I mean is you are not creating a compressed file that is in a ZIP format, so standard ZIP programs or handlers will think it is invalid. You are creating a single file that is multiple files appended together in a customised format, and then compressing that file into a gz file. When you deflate the file you will end up with the same file in the custom format which you will then need to process the individual bytes in order to obtain the original files.

Comment: @IanBoggs, I got you, thanks very much. I'm blocked, I don't know which namespace will help... I'm not allowed to use a 3rd party namespace. Would you have any suggestions? The input is a list of files, output is a .zip file.

Comment: @sven.xia ZipFile, as mentioned in Asunez's answer and by Martheen in the comments above, is your best solution. It is part of the same .NET library as GZipStream so you should be fine

Answer (score 2):

See Microsoft docs for help. It's literally first result on Google:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string startPath = @"c:\example\start";
            string zipPath = @"c:\example\result.zip";
            string extractPath = @"c:\example\extract";

            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);

            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
        }
    }
}
```

where `startPath` is the directory with files you want to zip together, `zipPath` is where you want the zip file to be created and `extractPath` is where these files should be extracted (the example shows both compression and extraction).

For more examples on how you can utilize `System.IO.Compression` namespace visit the source I provided below.

[(source)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-compress-and-extract-files)

Comment: Thanks. That's a little different. The source files may come from different paths such as @"c:\example\test1.txt“, @"c:\temp\test2.txt" etc. They have full paths stored in a string array.

Comment: But you can still do that with the MSDN link I provided